# How to display facebook profile pic in Flash AIR mobile app for ios

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, mobile, air

I am working on Flash AIR application for iphone, using "facebook-actionscript-api" for Mobile.

does anybody know how to display FB user's profile pic using above API?

Thanks & Regards,
Swati.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi is right! you always want answers! :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suposing that you already know how to login on FB Mobile.

FacebookMobile.api("/me", callbackFunction);
In the callback function you'll receive a lot data from the logged user.

If you are a newbie, come [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook/articles/flex_fbgraph_pt1.html). It's a article for Flex, but you can use the same info for anything in Flash.